# Ubuntu 16.10 throws WiFi

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have a PC with Ubuntu 16.10 and every time when the computer boots it throws the WiFi and I have to restart the router.

P.D.: sorry for my bad English, I am from Costa Rica

**Edit**

The command

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

No output

And the command

```
$ lspci -knn
```

Gives me this

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0150] (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard [1849:0150]
Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
Kernel modules: ie31200_edac
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0152] (rev 09)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [1849:0152]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [1849:1c3a]
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1849:1c2d]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [1849:3662]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b5)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [1849:1c26]
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c5c] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [1849:1c5c]
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c02] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [1849:1c02]
Kernel driver in use: ahci
Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1849:1c22]
Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

And the command `grep Net -A2` doesn't do anything

**Edit 2**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:6341 Microdia Defender G-Lens 2577 HD720p Camera
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:201d Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please what do you mean by _throws the wifi_, and _Ubuntu 16.10 Android_. Clarify!

Comment: The "Android" was the autocorrection of my phone and byb"throws" I mean the internet speed decreases to 0.10 mb/s or zero

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I do not see any wireless devices. Probably you are using a USB dongle.

Comment: Post the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Yes, I had to change my old adapter, I currently use aUSB Nexxt Nano Lynx

Comment: This is not a good choice of a wireless adapter for Linux. It is a known problem, but I have not heard of a solution.